# Child with -22 power, is it equal to blindness?

Tags: pediatrics, glasses, eye-strain, blind, color-blindness

Doctor have advised -22 power glasses for my 3-year old daughter. Does it equal to blindness? Will she behave like a normal child - play, fight and ask for different things (as children do), identify the colors etc?